# Putting a gridview row in edit mode programmatically

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How do I put a gridview row in edit mode programmatically?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set the EditIndex property to the appropriate row and then ReBind the GridVIew again to it's DataSource.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great.  I am using this as a hack to get the GridView to support inserts.  I'll note that you need to do everything in this order as directed in answer:

Answer (score 4):

Just implement the Row_Editing event and do something like this:

```
protected void Row_Editing(object sender, GridViewEditArgs e) 
{
  myGridView.EditItemIndex = e.EditItemIndex; 
  BindData(); 
}
```

Bind data will populate the GridView with the data.

Answer (score 4):

You may also need to know how to cancel the edit. Just like you set up the "OnRowEditing" command in the gridview, you need to set up the "OnRowCancelingEdit" command. The backend should look similar to this. (VB)

```
Sub gridView1_rowCanceling(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
    gridView1.EditIndex = -1
    BindData()  // <-- Whatever procedure you use to bind your data to the gridView
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void gridview_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    // Change the row state
    gv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit;           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = 1;
}
```

Tested with vs-2008. fork fine.