# Remembering the current index of a paged ASP.NET gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in ASP.NET. If I go to any page (obviously not the 1st page). edit a record (using a custom bound button as I have a custom appearance). When I edit the record, it does not display in the gridview so I refresh the page, to do so.

However, refreshing the page (done via C#), means that the current index of the grid is lost. How can I retain the current index?

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 web forms or 3.5 (not sure, need to check). But definately not MVC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the record you are editing has its own unique identifier, I would persist that in veiwstate or session. This covers the scenario where records are inserted or deleted. [This question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438116/asp-net-gridview-how-to-activate-edit-mode-based-on-id-datakey) might then help you on setting the active row based on item id as opposed to index.

I know its not exactly what you're looking for but it may be a useful approach.

Comment: I actually tried that. I think the page refresh (response.redirect to same page) screws it up. I fixed this anyway.

Comment: After Editing I re-query and rebind the data source to ensure the latest data is displayed. This is similar to refreshing with a response.redirect. If using response.redirect you could append the index or id to the query string in the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to keep page index value on edit button event. You can used view state or session. Then once the update is clicked, you can rebind the data and set the index based on the value you saved.