# Getting the index of the last row inserted in a GridView

Tags: asp.net

How do I get the row index of the last row inserted in a GridView considering the user may have custom ordering in the grid (I can't use the last row).

```
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSourceCompleteWidget.Insert();
        GridViewCompleteWidget.DataBind();
        GridViewCompleteWidget.EditIndex = ??????;
    }
```

I want to put the row into edit mode immediately after the insert occurs.

UPDATE

```
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SqlDataSourceCompleteWidget.InsertParameters.Add("EFFECTIVE_DATE", Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        SqlDataSourceCompleteWidget.InsertParameters[0].DefaultValue = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SqlDataSourceCompleteWidget.Insert();
        GridViewCompleteWidget.DataBind();
        GridViewCompleteWidget.EditIndex = 1;
    }

    private int mostRecentRowIndex = -1;
    protected void GridViewCompleteWidget_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        mostRecentRowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;

        //GridViewCompleteWidget.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
    }
```

Comment: You can check my updated answer if it fits

Answer (score 0):

You would want to handle the [`RowCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) event.  You can access the row data and identity/location using the [`GridViewRowEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs.aspx) object that is passed to this event handler.

```
  void YourGridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
      YourGridView.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that e.Row.RowIndex is always -1

Comment: Adding that also seems to crash the program (like it is an endless loop)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I worked off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438116/asp-net-gridview-how-to-activate-edit-mode-based-on-id-datakey)

I'm assuming you just return a value after doing the insert but you can set ID wherever you insert the record.

```
private int mostRecentRowIndex = -1;  //edit index
    private bool GridRebound = false;  //used to make sure we don't rebind
    private string ID;  //Is set to the last inserted ID

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Set so grid isn't rebound on postback
            GridRebound = true;
        }
    }

    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSourceCompleteWidget.InsertParameters[0].DefaultValue = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        ID = SqlDataSourceCompleteWidget.Insert();
        GridViewCompleteWidget.DataBind();
    }


    protected void GridViewCompleteWidget_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check that the row index >= 0 so it is a valid row with a datakey and compare 
        //the datakey to ID value
        if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 0 && GridViewCompleteWidget.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString() == ID)
        {
            //Set the edit index
            mostRecentRowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
        }
    }

    protected void GridViewCompleteWidget_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set Gridview edit index if isn't -1 and page is not a post back
        if (!GridRebound && mostRecentRowIndex >= 0)
        {
            //Setting GridRebound ensures this only happens once
            GridRebound = true;
            GridViewCompleteWidget.EditIndex = mostRecentRowIndex;
            GridViewCompleteWidget.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

**Selects if inserting last record in gridview (no sorting)**

You should be able to get the number of rows from the datasource: (minus 1 because the rows start at 0 and the count starts at 1)

```
GridViewCompleteWidget.EditIndex = ((DataTable)GridViewCompleteWidget.DataSource).Rows.Count - 1;
```

But put this before you bind the data:

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSourceCompleteWidget.Insert();
        GridViewCompleteWidget.EditIndex = ((DataTable)GridViewCompleteWidget.DataSource).Rows.Count - 1;
        GridViewCompleteWidget.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: This will get the last row (what if the user has sorted their controls in Descending order or something?)

Comment: @jax - Is there a unique identifier for each row in the data source?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Sorry I skipped that ordering was done by user. I've tested the following code and it works having respected the users ordering of items, but we must take the user to the page where the last row exists.

**1st:** Retrieve the Max(ID) from database  after insertion, store it in a session

```
 select Max(ID) from tbl_name; -- this statement can retrieve the last ID
Session["lastID"]=lastID;
```

**2nd:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{       
    if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    if (Session["lastID"] != null)
        if ((int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID") == (int)Session["lastID"])
        {
            //Session["rowIndex"] = e.Row.RowIndex;
            int rowIndex=e.Row.RowIndex;



            if (Session["type"] != null)
                if (Session["type"].ToString() == "Normal")
                {
                    int integ;
                    decimal fract;
                    integ = rowIndex / GridView1.PageSize;
                    fract = ((rowIndex / GridView1.PageSize) - integ;
                    if (fract > 0)
                        GridView1.PageIndex = integ;
                    else if (integ > 0) GridView1.PageIndex = integ - 1;

                    GridView1.EditIndex = rowIndex;
                }
        }
}
```

**3rd:** Convert your commandField into TemplateFields and Set their CommandArgument="Command"
    I'll use this argument to identify what triggered RowDataBound event. I store the value in a Session["type"]. The default value is "Normal" defined in the page load event.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
  Session["type"]="Normal";
```

the other value is set in RowCommand event

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandArgument == "Command")
        Session["type"] = "Command";
}
```

It works for me fine.

Sorry for my language and,may be, unnecessary details.

Answer (score 0):

Edit using the gridview's onitemcommand.  Then you can use a binding expression on the grid column to set whatever you want.  If you are using a button or linkbutton or several others you could use the CommandArgument

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DataPropertyIWant") %>'
```