# Gridview on direct edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want gridview directly on edit mode without any edit/update linkbutton on it and I want to update each row on every next different row selection. 
I have tried by putting textbox on itemTemplate and passed row index on row command (hidden button is created)updated on rowUpdating.

Any ideas?

Comment: Grid view have a specific way of working. Search and find some other custom grid view control to work the way you wont it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please visit [Putting a gridview row in edit mode programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206983/putting-a-gridview-row-in-edit-mode-programmatically) . There is accpeted answers. Hope, some of them works for you.

Answer (score 1):

use component one flexgrid http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/FlexGridWinForms/ this will help u

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I understood you well but you could use [CellEndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx) event on your datagridview?