# Gridview Edit update Delete by on row click Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Update And Cancel button not functioning and these buttons are out side from the gridview

**Scenario:**
The problem with the default asp.net gridview design is that the GridView edit column always occupies some screen real estate. Additionally in the edit mode the GridView expands horizontally disturbing the page layout. that`s why i want to render an editable GridView without displaying the default Edit, Update and Cancel buttons

**Example:**

[image]

**What i have done already**

when you see the html source of Gridview you will find the following Edit, Update, cancel Link button with an event called dopostback

**e.g**

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView2;Edit${1};)">Edit</a>
```

If you somehow generate the same above script and execute it for some client side event (click of a button for example) then you can essentially send the same commands to the GridView control. The easiest way to do so is to handle RowDataBound event of the GridView Control so i decided to use it on RowDataBound event of Gridview control as shown below:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == GridView2.EditIndex)
            {
                //update or cancel buttons
                LinkButton updateBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
                string updateScript = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(updateBtn, "");
                Button1.Attributes["onclick"] = updateScript;

                string cancelScript = string.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView2','Cancel${1}')",
                                      GridView1.ID, e.Row.RowIndex);
                Button2.Attributes["onclick"] = cancelScript;
            }
            else
            {
                //edit button
                string editScript = string.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView2','Edit${1}')",
                                    GridView1.ID, e.Row.RowIndex);
                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = editScript;
            }

        }
        if (GridView2.EditIndex >= 0)
        {
            Button1.Enabled = true;
            Button2.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Now when i click on any row of gridview it will become an editable row which should be cancel and update by the cancel and update button which are outside of the gridview but they are not working...

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated .

**Note:** still you need to include the edit,update, cancel linkbutton in Gridview which you can latter hide from the gridview by using script like jquery below..

e.g

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#GridView2 th:first-child").hide();
    $("#GridView2 td:first-child").hide();
});
```

Comment: Are you dealing with `OnRowCancelingEdit`, `OnRowUpdating` events of the gridview?

Comment: @HassanNisar  no i am not i am just handling the Genrated Event of dopostback event of Edit, Update and Delete linkbutton
The __doPostBack() call of the Edit button takes ID of the GridView as the first parameter and row number in the form Edit$<row_number> as the second parameter. The __doPostBack() call of the Update button passes the first parameter as the control's unique ID. The __doPostBack() of the Cancel button is quite similar to Edit button except that instead of Edit the command name used is Cancel

Comment: Please stay away from calling __doPostback directly, this is a terrible hack, as doPostback has the underlines for a reason (should be considered private). I will post an answer shortly that should be of help.

Comment: @julealgon i am not afraid by using dopostback driectly Because it can be handled easily to save from any hack. waiting for your kind reply

Comment: @SiddiqBaig where you are updating row? Is there any server-side event handler for `updateBtn`?

Comment: @HassanNisar yes updatebtn is hyperlink out side from the gridview which i designed like button

Comment: What are `Button1` and `Button2` then?

Comment: @HassanNisar updateBtn Basically update hyperlink inside Gridview sorry i am tiered and did`nt get your point.. what i am doing i am checking the condition if e.row.rowindex equal to -1 then it should be update or Cancel elase edit

Comment: @SiddiqBaig I understand. `updateBtn` is the `LinkButton` you hide using jQuery. But can you tell how you update records?

Comment: when e.row.rowindex meet the condition then i am assigning the _doPostBack event to Button1 that is basically a Update button.. here how i am trying to update records

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are just trying to remove the edit/update buttons from inside the grid to an external location.

You can programmatically set the edit index of the grid, [by setting it's `EditIndex` property to the index you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206983/putting-a-gridview-row-in-edit-mode-programmatically). You can of course base this decision on the currently selected row of the grid.

After that, you need to databind the grid and change your button from "Edit" to "Update" (if you are using a toggle like solution) or enable/disable them as needed.

The logic for the update can then use the `UpdateRow` method on the Grid to persist the changes. You can follow the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.updaterow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see how to force the edit programmatically. In your case, on button click, you need to pass in the current edit index, like this:

```
myGrid.UpdateRow(myGrid.EditIndex, true);
```

EDIT:

I completely bypassed the fact that you want the edit to happen on row click, and that is not as easy to do since clicking the row will not cause a postback. You can probably use something like [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1666327.aspx?click%20row%20on%20gridview%20and%20trigger%20postback%20c%20) to that effect. It basically boils down to setting a client side event on the entire row at creation on the server. I have not tested that though, and I personally think that part alone should be another question entirely since it can be isolated to "how to cause a postback from a row click of a gridview".

Comment: yup you got my point i want to remove the edit update buttons from inside the gridview.. however you can not achieve this task by using EditIndex of Gridview because you need to put the cancel, update button inside the Gridview

Comment: @julealgon can you explain more. How to use `UpdateRow`?

Comment: @SiddiqBaig I mentioned that you can use the `UpdateRow` method to force the update of the row from outside too. You can cancel the edit by setting the `EditIndex` to -1 if I recall correctly. Isn't that what you want to achieve?

Comment: i got your pint i will try it soon

Comment: @HassanNisar Updated the question with a bit more info on that, hopefully it's enough to understand.

Comment: @julealgon if you test the above code you will find the row will become an editable by clicking any row! i just want to cancel and update from out side the grid please test it

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for that. Replace your GridView1_RowDataBound function body with that:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == GridView1.EditIndex)
            {
                //update or cancel buttons
                LinkButton updateBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
                string updateScript = string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').click(); return false;", updateBtn.ClientID);
                Button1.OnClientClick = updateScript;

                LinkButton cancelBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2];
                string cancelScript = string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').click(); return false;", cancelBtn.ClientID);
                Button2.OnClientClick = cancelScript;
            }
            else
            {
                //edit button
                LinkButton editBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
                string editScript = string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').click();", editBtn.ClientID);
                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = editScript;
            }

        }
        if (GridView1.EditIndex >= 0)
        {
            Button1.Enabled = true;
            Button2.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

First I got rid of js calls to __doPostBack with isn't good practice as julealgon mentioned in comments. Instead of that I build script that does getElementById, searches for particular linkbutton by unique client id and simulates 'click' on that link. All link buttons are still on the form but are hidden as you call your document.ready script so you won't get js error 'item not found...'

Second very important thing is to return 'false' at the end of OnClientClick script for Button1 and Button2 (OnClientClick works the same as Attributes["onclick"]).

This is to prevent button postback, without that another postback is triggered by button itself and because there is no OnClick event implemented server-side that rebinds grid and sets editindex some information is lost and when 'grid' postback is triggered (proper one, caused by link button) it does not work.

My answers assumes that all grid's server-side events like RowUpdating, RowCancelingEdit and RowEditing work or that your grid has related SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource that implements those. In another words I assume that if you use generated Edit, Update, Cancel buttons in grid rows it all works as expected.